# My app get killed (Fatal signal 11)

Tags: android, kill

My android app sometimes gets totally killed and after searching through Logcat I got the following:

```
03-31 13:45:50.512: E/dalvikvm(14458): VM aborting
03-31 13:45:50.512: A/libc(14458): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 14458 (omation.isolace)
03-31 13:45:50.512: D/AEE/AED(131): $===AEE===AEE===AEE===$
03-31 13:45:50.512: D/AEE/AED(131): p 0 poll events 1 revents 0
03-31 13:45:50.512: D/AEE/AED(131): not know revents:0
03-31 13:45:50.512: D/AEE/AED(131): p 1 poll events 1 revents 0
03-31 13:45:50.512: D/AEE/AED(131): not know revents:0
03-31 13:45:50.512: D/AEE/AED(131): p 2 poll events 1 revents 1
03-31 13:45:50.512: D/AEE/AED(131): aed_main_fork_worker: generator 0x1300168, worker 0xbee0a9d8, recv_fd 15
03-31 13:45:50.512: D/AEE/AED(131): p 3 poll events 1 revents 0
03-31 13:45:50.512: D/AEE/AED(131): not know revents:0

03-31 13:45:50.514: I/DEBUG(14626): [OnPurpose Redunant in preset_info] pid: 14458, tid: 14458, name: omation.isolace  >>> com.automation.isolace <<<
03-31 13:45:50.615: I/DEBUG(14626): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
03-31 13:45:50.615: I/DEBUG(14626): Build fingerprint: 'Lenovo/LenovoA3000-H/A3000:4.2.2/JDQ39/A3000_A422_011_022_140127_WW_C:user/release-keys'
03-31 13:45:50.615: I/DEBUG(14626): pid: 14458, tid: 14458, name: omation.isolace  >>> com.automation.isolace <<<
03-31 13:45:50.615: I/DEBUG(14626): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadd00d
03-31 13:45:50.732: I/DEBUG(14626):     r0 00000000  r1 00000000  r2 deadd00d  r3 00000000
03-31 13:45:50.732: I/DEBUG(14626):     r4 40c0a1b0  r5 0000020c  r6 000685ec  r7 00000001
03-31 13:45:50.732: I/DEBUG(14626):     r8 000685ec  r9 00000000  sl 00000000  fp 00000000
03-31 13:45:50.732: I/DEBUG(14626):     ip 00004000  sp be8b7af0  lr 400b011c  pc 40b9b064  cpsr 60000030
03-31 13:45:50.736: I/DEBUG(14626): backtrace:
03-31 13:45:50.736: I/DEBUG(14626):     #00  pc 00046064  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmAbort+75)
03-31 13:45:50.736: I/DEBUG(14626):     #01  pc 0003c0cd  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-31 13:45:50.737: I/DEBUG(14626):     #02  pc 000746b7  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (GraphicsJNI::allocateJavaPixelRef(_JNIEnv*, SkBitmap*, SkColorTable*)+130)
03-31 13:45:50.737: I/DEBUG(14626):     #03  pc 000746db  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (JavaPixelAllocator::allocPixelRef(SkBitmap*, SkColorTable*)+18)

03-31 13:45:50.739: I/DEBUG(14626):     #01  be8b7d08  404328c0  /system/lib/libjpeg.so
03-31 13:45:50.739: I/DEBUG(14626):          be8b7d0c  00000000  
03-31 13:45:50.739: I/DEBUG(14626):          be8b7d10  00000000  
03-31 13:45:50.739: I/DEBUG(14626):          be8b7d14  40fae710  [heap]
03-31 13:45:50.739: I/DEBUG(14626):          be8b7d18  40bffe55  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-31 13:45:50.739: I/DEBUG(14626):          be8b7d1c  00000000  
03-31 13:45:50.739: I/DEBUG(14626):          be8b7d20  00000001  
03-31 13:45:50.739: I/DEBUG(14626):          be8b7d24  0000011d  
03-31 13:45:50.739: I/DEBUG(14626):          be8b7d28  00000000  
03-31 13:45:50.739: I/DEBUG(14626):          be8b7d2c  be8b9368  [stack]
03-31 13:45:50.739: I/DEBUG(14626):          be8b7d30  be8b92b4  [stack]
03-31 13:45:50.739: I/DEBUG(14626):          be8b7d34  be8b92b4  [stack]
03-31 13:45:50.739: I/DEBUG(14626):          be8b7d38  40fae710  [heap]
03-31 13:45:50.739: I/DEBUG(14626):          be8b7d3c  4020d6b9  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (GraphicsJNI::allocateJavaPixelRef(_JNIEnv*, SkBitmap*, SkColorTable*)+132)
03-31 13:45:50.739: I/DEBUG(14626):     #02  be8b7d40  40bffba7  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-31 13:45:50.739: I/DEBUG(14626):          be8b7d44  00008000  
03-31 13:45:50.739: I/DEBUG(14626):          be8b7d48  00000000  
03-31 13:45:50.739: I/DEBUG(14626):          be8b7d4c  000685ec  
03-31 13:45:50.739: I/DEBUG(14626):          be8b7d50  53a8b120  
03-31 13:45:50.739: I/DEBUG(14626):          be8b7d54  be8b9368  [stack]
03-31 13:45:50.739: I/DEBUG(14626):          be8b7d58  00000000  
03-31 13:45:50.739: I/DEBUG(14626):          be8b7d5c  be8b92b4  [stack]
03-31 13:45:50.739: I/DEBUG(14626):          be8b7d60  00000001  
03-31 13:45:50.739: I/DEBUG(14626):          be8b7d64  00000000  
03-31 13:45:50.739: I/DEBUG(14626):          be8b7d68  00000000  
03-31 13:45:50.740: I/DEBUG(14626):          be8b7d6c  0000011d  
03-31 13:45:50.740: I/DEBUG(14626):          be8b7d70  00000000  
03-31 13:45:50.740: I/DEBUG(14626):          be8b7d74  4020d6df  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (JavaPixelAllocator::allocPixelRef(SkBitmap*, SkColorTable*)+22)
03-31 13:45:50.748: I/DEBUG(14626): memory near r4:
03-31 13:45:50.748: I/DEBUG(14626):     40c0a190 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
03-31 13:45:50.748: I/DEBUG(14626):     40c0a1a0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
03-31 13:45:50.748: I/DEBUG(14626):     40c0a1b0 40fae730 40fadbb8 00400000 08000000  0..@...@..@.....
03-31 13:45:50.748: I/DEBUG(14626):     40c0a1c0 06000000 00000000 00000000 3fe00000  ...............?
03-31 13:45:50.748: I/DEBUG(14626):     40c0a1d0 00200000 00800000 00008000 00006000  .. ..........`..
03-31 13:45:50.748: I/DEBUG(14626): memory near r6:
03-31 13:45:50.749: I/DEBUG(14626):     000685cc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
03-31 13:45:50.749: I/DEBUG(14626):     000685dc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
03-31 13:45:50.749: I/DEBUG(14626):     000685ec ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
03-31 13:45:50.749: I/DEBUG(14626):     000685fc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
03-31 13:45:50.749: I/DEBUG(14626):     0006860c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
03-31 13:45:50.749: I/DEBUG(14626): memory near r8:
03-31 13:45:50.749: I/DEBUG(14626):     000685cc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
03-31 13:45:50.749: I/DEBUG(14626):     000685dc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
03-31 13:45:50.749: I/DEBUG(14626):     000685ec ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
03-31 13:45:50.749: I/DEBUG(14626):     000685fc ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
03-31 13:45:50.749: I/DEBUG(14626):     0006860c ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
03-31 13:45:50.749: I/DEBUG(14626): memory near ip:
03-31 13:45:50.749: I/DEBUG(14626):     00003fe0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
03-31 13:45:50.749: I/DEBUG(14626):     00003ff0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
03-31 13:45:50.749: I/DEBUG(14626):     00004000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
03-31 13:45:50.749: I/DEBUG(14626):     00004010 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
03-31 13:45:50.749: I/DEBUG(14626):     00004020 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
03-31 13:45:50.749: I/DEBUG(14626): memory near sp:
03-31 13:45:50.749: I/DEBUG(14626):     be8b7ad0 00000000 400b1d60 40c0a1b0 0000020c  ....`..@...@....
03-31 13:45:50.749: I/DEBUG(14626):     be8b7ae0 000685ec 00000001 df0027ad 00000000  .........'......
03-31 13:45:50.749: I/DEBUG(14626):     be8b7af0 40f57eb8 6c756e28 0000296c 00000000  .~.@(null)......
03-31 13:45:50.749: I/DEBUG(14626):     be8b7b00 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
03-31 13:45:50.749: I/DEBUG(14626):     be8b7b10 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ................
03-31 13:45:50.749: I/DEBUG(14626): code around pc:
03-31 13:45:50.750: I/DEBUG(14626):     40b9b044 447a34d4 ee8af7d7 461d2300 b1525d1a  .4zD.....#.F.]R.
03-31 13:45:50.750: I/DEBUG(14626):     40b9b054 18ad3301 7f00f5b3 e004d1f8 4a0a4798  .3...........G.J
03-31 13:45:50.750: I/DEBUG(14626):     40b9b064 f7d77015 490cee82 4a0c2006 44794c0c  .p.....I. .J.LyD
03-31 13:45:50.750: I/DEBUG(14626):     40b9b074 f7d7447a 447ced1e f7d72000 6de3edce  zD....|D. .....m
03-31 13:45:50.750: I/DEBUG(14626):     40b9b084 d1eb2b00 bf00e7eb deadd00d 0006aace  .+..............
03-31 13:45:50.750: I/DEBUG(14626): code around lr:
03-31 13:45:50.750: I/DEBUG(14626):     400b00fc e1a00005 ebffffcf e1a06000 e5940000  .........`......
03-31 13:45:50.750: I/DEBUG(14626):     400b010c e3500000 0a000001 e1a00005 eb0001f2  ..P.............
03-31 13:45:50.750: I/DEBUG(14626):     400b011c e1a00006 e8bd8070 eb0001e3 eafffff3  ....p...........
03-31 13:45:50.750: I/DEBUG(14626):     400b012c 0003de54 e92d4070 e2505000 0a000018  T...p@-..PP.....
03-31 13:45:50.750: I/DEBUG(14626):     400b013c e59f406c e79f4004 e5943000 e3530000  l@...@...0....S.
03-31 13:45:50.750: I/DEBUG(14626): memory map around fault addr deadd00d:
03-31 13:45:50.750: I/DEBUG(14626):     be899000-be8ba000 [stack]
03-31 13:45:50.750: I/DEBUG(14626):     (no map for address)
03-31 13:45:50.750: I/DEBUG(14626):     ffff0000-ffff1000 [vectors]
03-31 13:45:51.104: D/AEE/AED(14626): Skip for Exp level'0'
03-31 13:45:51.104: V/Provider/Settings(504):  from settings cache , name = dropbox:SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE , value = null
03-31 13:45:51.104: D/AEE/AED(131): $===AEE===AEE===AEE===$
03-31 13:45:51.104: D/AEE/AED(131): p 0 poll events 1 revents 0
03-31 13:45:51.104: D/AEE/AED(131): not know revents:0
03-31 13:45:51.104: D/AEE/AED(131): p 1 poll events 1 revents 0
03-31 13:45:51.104: D/AEE/AED(131): not know revents:0
03-31 13:45:51.104: D/AEE/AED(131): p 2 poll events 1 revents 0
03-31 13:45:51.104: D/AEE/AED(131): not know revents:0
03-31 13:45:51.104: D/AEE/AED(131): p 3 poll events 1 revents 0
03-31 13:45:51.104: D/AEE/AED(131): not know revents:0
03-31 13:45:51.104: D/AEE/AED(131): p 4 poll events 1 revents 0
03-31 13:45:51.104: D/AEE/AED(131): not know revents:0
03-31 13:45:51.105: I/BootReceiver(504): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_04 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
03-31 13:45:51.156: D/IPCThreadState(504): [DN #5] BR_DEAD_BINDER cookie 0x56aaa128
03-31 13:45:51.156: D/IPCThreadState(504): [DN #5] BR_DEAD_BINDER cookie 0x5693fe80
03-31 13:45:51.156: D/IPCThreadState(504): [DN #5] BR_DEAD_BINDER cookie 0x579e0b60
03-31 13:45:51.156: D/IPCThreadState(504): [DN #5] BR_DEAD_BINDER cookie 0x5693ff18
03-31 13:45:51.156: D/IPCThreadState(504): [DN #5] BR_DEAD_BINDER cookie 0x56b09348
03-31 13:45:51.157: D/ADB_SERVICES(170):  closing because is_eof=1 r=0 s->fde.force_eof=0
03-31 13:45:51.157: I/SurfaceFlinger(138): EventThread Client Pid (14458) disconnected by (138)
03-31 13:45:51.157: W/ADB_SERVICES(170): terminating JDWP 14458 connection: Try again
03-31 13:45:51.157: D/ADB_SERVICES(170): remove pid 14458 to jdwp process list
03-31 13:45:51.163: D/dalvikvm(504): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 266K (2051), 28% free 9851K/13536K, paused 57ms, total 57ms
03-31 13:45:51.164: D/IPCThreadState(504): [DN #5] BR_CLEAR_DEATH_NOTIFICATION_DONE cookie 0x5693fe80
03-31 13:45:51.164: D/IPCThreadState(504): [DN #5] BR_CLEAR_DEATH_NOTIFICATION_DONE cookie 0x5693ff18
03-31 13:45:51.165: V/ActivityManager(504): Death received in com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$AppDeathRecipient@41aed290 for thread android.os.BinderProxy@41aeccf0
03-31 13:45:51.165: I/WindowState(504): WIN DEATH: Window{41a3ec48 u0 com.automation.isolace/com.automation.isolace.HomeView}
03-31 13:45:51.165: I/ActivityManager(504): Process com.automation.isolace (pid 14458) has died.
03-31 13:45:51.166: V/NetworkStats(504): setKernelCounterSet uid=10095 set=0
03-31 13:45:51.168: I/SurfaceTexture(138): [com.automation.isolace/com.automation.isolace.HomeView](this:0x41cdc070,api:1) destroying EGLImage dpy=0x1 img=0x41cddba0
03-31 13:45:51.168: I/SurfaceTexture(138): [com.automation.isolace/com.automation.isolace.HomeView](this:0x41cdc070,api:1) destroying EGLImage dpy=0x1 img=0x41cc79b0
03-31 13:45:51.168: I/SurfaceTexture(138): [com.automation.isolace/com.automation.isolace.HomeView](this:0x41cdc070,api:1) destroying EGLImage dpy=0x1 img=0x41cd1b28
03-31 13:45:51.168: I/SurfaceTexture(138): [com.automation.isolace/com.automation.isolace.HomeView](this:0x41cdc070,api:1) destroying EGLImage dpy=0x1 img=0x41cd4ff0
03-31 13:45:51.168: I/BufferQueue(138): [com.automation.isolace/com.automation.isolace.HomeView](this:0x41ccba18,api:1) consumerDisconnect
03-31 13:45:51.169: I/BufferQueue(138): [com.automation.isolace/com.automation.isolace.HomeView](this:0x41ccba18,api:1) ~BufferQueue
03-31 13:45:51.213: I/SurfaceFlinger(138): [SurfaceFlinger] fps:1.737453,dur:3453.33,max:2520.10,min:50.06
03-31 13:45:51.228: D/dalvikvm(504): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 35K (252), 27% free 9947K/13536K, paused 60ms, total 60ms
03-31 13:45:51.228: I/dalvikvm-heap(504): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.985MB for 131088-byte allocation
03-31 13:45:51.232: D/InputReader(504): AP_PROF:AppLaunch_dispatchPtr:Down:26500953
03-31 13:45:51.232: I/AP_PROF(504): unable to open /proc/mtprof/status entry
03-31 13:45:51.267: D/Zygote(139): Process 14458 terminated by signal (11)
```

In fact I can't get the reason from the Logcat of why this happens, also I can't figure out what is the part of my code that may causes this.

**UPDATE:**
According to Nicola's answer, I reproduced the kill-process again and before the line of `Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)`, I did find the following lines:

```
03-31 15:14:48.945: E/dalvikvm-heap(15312): Out of memory on a 427516-byte allocation.
03-31 15:14:48.945: I/dalvikvm(15312): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
03-31 15:14:48.945: I/dalvikvm(15312):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40fbfa18 self=0x40faef10
03-31 15:14:48.945: I/dalvikvm(15312):   | sysTid=15312 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074264156
03-31 15:14:48.945: I/dalvikvm(15312):   | state=R schedstat=( 30224201008 6455675663 51891 ) utm=2378 stm=644 core=0
03-31 15:14:48.945: I/dalvikvm(15312):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeByteArray(Native Method)
03-31 15:14:48.945: I/dalvikvm(15312):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:447)
03-31 15:14:48.945: I/dalvikvm(15312):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:465)
03-31 15:14:48.945: I/dalvikvm(15312):   at com.automation.isolace.Media.set_movies(Media.java:3096)
03-31 15:14:48.945: I/dalvikvm(15312):   at com.automation.isolace.Login.xbmc_parse_response(Login.java:1205)
03-31 15:14:48.945: I/dalvikvm(15312):   at com.automation.isolace.Login.xbmc_response_received(Login.java:865)
03-31 15:14:48.945: I/dalvikvm(15312):   at com.automation.connections.MediaConnections$1.run(MediaConnections.java:223)
03-31 15:14:48.945: I/dalvikvm(15312):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-31 15:14:48.945: I/dalvikvm(15312):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-31 15:14:48.946: I/dalvikvm(15312):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
03-31 15:14:48.946: I/dalvikvm(15312):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
03-31 15:14:48.946: I/dalvikvm(15312):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-31 15:14:48.946: I/dalvikvm(15312):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-31 15:14:48.946: I/dalvikvm(15312):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
03-31 15:14:48.946: I/dalvikvm(15312):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
03-31 15:14:48.946: I/dalvikvm(15312):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-31 15:14:48.946: W/mHalJpgDec(15312): mHalJpgDec:: enter start L:195!!
03-31 15:14:48.946: W/mHalJpgDec(15312): mHalJpgDec:: cancel Decoder L:200!!
03-31 15:14:48.946: W/JpgDecPipe(15312): ::[UNLOCK] unlock , islock 1!!
03-31 15:14:48.946: D/JpgDecComp(15312): unlock!!
03-31 15:14:48.946: D/ImgScaler(15312): ::gdmaCtrUnlock, L:488!!
03-31 15:14:48.946: D/ImgScaler(15312): ::ScalerDeInit, reset_flag 0, L:890!!
03-31 15:14:48.946: I/iio/cdp(15312): [uninit] :E. meScenarioID: 11.
03-31 15:14:48.946: I/IspDrv(15312): {IspDrv} [GlobalPipeCountDec] - E.
03-31 15:14:48.946: I/IspDrv(15312): {IspDrv} [GlobalPipeCountDec] - X. Result: 1. count: 0.
03-31 15:14:48.946: I/CdpDrv(15312): {CdpDrv} [Uninit]  - E. mInitCount: 1. mSysramUsageCount: 0.
03-31 15:14:48.946: I/CdpDrv(15312): {CdpDrv} [ProfilingPrint] [Event_CdpDrv_Uninit] atomic_dec:(0-th) ===> [start-->now: 0.027000 ms]
03-31 15:14:48.946: I/CdpDrv(15312): {CdpDrv} [Uninit]  - X. Result: 1. mInitCount: 0. mFdSysram: -1. mSysramUsageCount: 0.
03-31 15:14:48.946: I/CdpDrv(15312): {CdpDrv} [ProfilingPrint] [Event_CdpDrv_Uninit] Exit:(1-th) ===> [start-->now: 0.058000 ms] [last-->now: 0.031000 ms]
03-31 15:14:48.946: I/CdpDrv(15312): {CdpDrv} [DestroyInstance] 
03-31 15:14:48.946: I/iio/ifunc(15312): [ProfilingPrint] [Event_IspDrvShellImp_Uninit] delete mpM4UDrv:(0-th) ===> 0.035000 ms (Total time till now: 0.036000 ms)
03-31 15:14:48.946: I/IspDrv(15312): {IspDrv} [uninit]  - E. mInitCount(1)
03-31 15:14:48.946: I/IspDrv(15312): {IspDrv} [ProfilingPrint] [Event_IspDrv_Uninit] atomic_dec:(0-th) ===> [start-->now: 0.008000 ms]
03-31 15:14:48.946: I/IspDrv(15312): {IspDrv} [uninit] ISP Global Count: 0.
03-31 15:14:48.946: I/IspDrv(15312): {IspDrv} [ProfilingPrint] [Event_IspDrv_Uninit] close isp mFd:(1-th) ===> [start-->now: 0.208000 ms] [last-->now: 0.200000 ms]
03-31 15:14:48.946: I/IspDrv(15312): {IspDrv} [ProfilingPrint] [Event_IspDrv_Uninit] free(mpIspDrvRegMap):(2-th) ===> [start-->now: 0.226000 ms] [last-->now: 0.018000 ms]
03-31 15:14:48.946: I/IspDrv(15312): {IspDrv} [uninit]  - X. ret: 1. mInitCount: 0.
03-31 15:14:48.946: I/IspDrv(15312): {IspDrv} [ProfilingPrint] [Event_IspDrv_Uninit] Exit:(3-th) ===> [start-->now: 0.245000 ms] [last-->now: 0.019000 ms]
03-31 15:14:48.946: I/iio/ifunc(15312): [uninit] mInitCount(0)
03-31 15:14:48.946: D/ResMgrDrv(15312): [Uninit]More user(1)
03-31 15:14:48.947: I/iio/cdp(15312): [uninit] :X
03-31 15:14:48.947: I/iio/cdpb(15312): [uninit] - mu4InitRefCount(0), ret(1)
03-31 15:14:48.947: D/PipeMgrDrv(15312): [Unlock]OK,PipeMask(0x00000010)
03-31 15:14:48.947: D/PipeMgrDrv(15312): [Uninit]Last user(0)
03-31 15:14:48.947: D/ResMgrDrv(15312): [Uninit]Last user(0)
03-31 15:14:48.947: D/ImgScaler(15312): ::ScalerDeInit done, L:937!!
03-31 15:14:48.947: D/ImgScaler(15312): ::freeMEM, L:1843!!
03-31 15:14:48.947: D/JpgDecComp(15312): JpgDecComp::~JpgDecComp
03-31 15:14:48.947: D/ImgScaler(15312): ImgCdpPipe::~ImgCdpPipe
03-31 15:14:48.947: D/JpgDecPipe(15312): JpgDecPipe::~JpgDecPipe
03-31 15:14:48.947: D/skia(15312): SkiaJpeg:TRY_SW_PATH no_eoi 0, mSize 13460, rSize 3424, align rSize 3440, skSize 3424!!
03-31 15:14:48.947: W/skia(15312): Use JPEG SW Decoder
03-31 15:14:48.947: W/dalvikvm(15312): JNI WARNING: JNI method called with exception pending
03-31 15:14:48.947: W/dalvikvm(15312):              in Landroid/graphics/BitmapFactory;.nativeDecodeByteArray:([BIILandroid/graphics/BitmapFactory$Options;)Landroid/graphics/Bitmap; (NewByteArray)
03-31 15:14:48.947: W/dalvikvm(15312): Pending exception is:
03-31 15:14:48.947: I/dalvikvm(15312): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:
03-31 15:14:48.947: I/dalvikvm(15312):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeByteArray(Native Method)
03-31 15:14:48.947: I/dalvikvm(15312):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:447)
03-31 15:14:48.947: I/dalvikvm(15312):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:465)
03-31 15:14:48.947: I/dalvikvm(15312):  at com.automation.isolace.Media.set_movies(Media.java:3096)
03-31 15:14:48.947: I/dalvikvm(15312):  at com.automation.isolace.Login.xbmc_parse_response(Login.java:1205)
03-31 15:14:48.947: I/dalvikvm(15312):  at com.automation.isolace.Login.xbmc_response_received(Login.java:865)
03-31 15:14:48.947: I/dalvikvm(15312):  at com.automation.connections.MediaConnections$1.run(MediaConnections.java:223)
03-31 15:14:48.947: I/dalvikvm(15312):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-31 15:14:48.947: I/dalvikvm(15312):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-31 15:14:48.947: I/dalvikvm(15312):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
03-31 15:14:48.947: I/dalvikvm(15312):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
03-31 15:14:48.947: I/dalvikvm(15312):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-31 15:14:48.947: I/dalvikvm(15312):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-31 15:14:48.947: I/dalvikvm(15312):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
03-31 15:14:48.947: I/dalvikvm(15312):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
03-31 15:14:48.947: I/dalvikvm(15312):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-31 15:14:48.947: I/dalvikvm(15312): "main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
03-31 15:14:48.947: I/dalvikvm(15312):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40fbfa18 self=0x40faef10
03-31 15:14:48.947: I/dalvikvm(15312):   | sysTid=15312 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074264156
03-31 15:14:48.948: I/dalvikvm(15312):   | state=R schedstat=( 30224201008 6455675663 51891 ) utm=2378 stm=644 core=0
03-31 15:14:48.948: D/dalvikvm(15312): dump native stack for : main
03-31 15:14:48.948: D/dalvikvm(15312): unwind backtrace
03-31 15:14:48.963: D/dalvikvm(15312): get native symbol
03-31 15:14:48.965: D/dalvikvm(15312): format backtrace line
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   #00  pc 000012a0  /system/lib/libcorkscrew.so (unwind_backtrace_thread+27)
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   #01  pc 0006118e  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpNativeStack(DebugOutputTarget const*, int)+53)
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   #02  pc 00054aaa  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpThreadEx(DebugOutputTarget const*, Thread*, bool)+329)
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   #03  pc 00054b4a  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpThread(Thread*, bool)+25)
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   #04  pc 00038eba  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   #05  pc 0003c0cc  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   #06  pc 000746b4  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (GraphicsJNI::allocateJavaPixelRef(_JNIEnv*, SkBitmap*, SkColorTable*)+127)
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   #07  pc 000746da  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (JavaPixelAllocator::allocPixelRef(SkBitmap*, SkColorTable*)+17)
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   #08  pc 00049bac  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkBitmap::allocPixels(SkBitmap::Allocator*, SkColorTable*)+56)
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   #09  pc 000b79f4  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkJPEGImageDecoder::onDecode(SkStream*, SkBitmap*, SkImageDecoder::Mode)+4896)
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   #10  pc 000b2998  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkImageDecoder::decode(SkStream*, SkBitmap*, SkBitmap::Config, SkImageDecoder::Mode, bool)+172)
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   #11  pc 0007164c  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   #12  pc 00071af0  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   #13  pc 0001e4d0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   #14  pc 0004ddf8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+499)
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   #15  pc 000278a0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   #16  pc 0002b804  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+180)
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   #17  pc 000613ce  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+373)
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   #18  pc 000692e8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   #19  pc 000278a0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   #20  pc 0002b804  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+180)
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   #21  pc 000610a8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+271)
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   #22  pc 0004a0d0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   #23  pc 0004d126  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   #24  pc 0004decc  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+399)
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   #25  pc 00000db6  /system/bin/app_process
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   #26  pc 0001bd98  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+64)
03-31 15:14:48.965: D/dalvikvm(15312): get native done
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeByteArray(Native Method)
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:447)
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:465)
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   at com.automation.isolace.Media.set_movies(Media.java:3096)
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   at com.automation.isolace.Login.xbmc_parse_response(Login.java:1205)
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   at com.automation.isolace.Login.xbmc_response_received(Login.java:865)
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   at com.automation.connections.MediaConnections$1.run(MediaConnections.java:223)
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
03-31 15:14:48.965: I/dalvikvm(15312):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-31 15:14:48.965: E/dalvikvm(15312): VM aborting
```

The line reported is:

```
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
                            decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

but this line is surrounded with try,catch:

```
            try {
                byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(def_value,
                        Base64.DEFAULT);
                Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
                        decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
                movies_bitmaps.put(movie_id_num_loader, decodedByte);
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError oom) {
              // So the OOM error got be catched here, So why causing a problem if it's the reason?
            }
```

Comment: Are you using the NDK? Is a third-party library that you are referencing using the NDK?

Comment: @CommonsWare No I'm not using NDK, although I'm using two libraries (universal-image-loader https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) and (java-json)

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not aware that either of those use the NDK. This is a core dump, which should not occur from Android SDK code. If you can reproduce this on an emulator, a Nexus device, or on hardware from multiple manufacturers, that would indicate a platform bug. If this can only be reproduced on this one device, then probably it is a manufacturer-specific bug.

Comment: @CommonsWare In fact it happened with me only with a certain device, and I'll try to reproduce it on any other device to know if it's a manufacturer-specific bug or not

Answer (score 2):

It seems that ART is unable to allocate memory for the `Bitmap` you are trying to decode.

You can see that the crash occurred on native level:

```
/system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmAbort+75)
03-31 13:45:50.736: I/DEBUG(14626):     #01  pc 0003c0cd  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-31 13:45:50.737: I/DEBUG(14626):     #02  pc 000746b7  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (GraphicsJNI::allocateJavaPixelRef(_JNIEnv*, SkBitmap*, SkColorTable*)+130)
03-31 13:45:50.737: I/DEBUG(14626):     #03  pc 000746db  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (JavaPixelAllocator::allocPixelRef(SkBitmap*, SkColorTable*)+18)
03-31 13:45:50.737: I/DEBUG(14626):     #04  pc 00049bac  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkBitmap::allocPixels(SkBitmap::Allocator*, SkColorTable*)+56)
```

Could be that it can't allocate for some reason or it has allocated too much memory.

Debug at which point it does crash. Perhaps it happens somewhere you are trying to decode bitmap, look for these lines.

Comment: Well, thanks for your observation, kindly have a look at my new updates to see if this is really what causes the problem